# Is it possible to have multiple listagg statements referencing more than one table in one query?

Tags: oracle, listagg

I have three LISTAGG statements that look like this:

```
LISTAGG (ga.FULL_APPL_NUM, ',') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY   ga.FULL_APPL_NUM) AS "FullApplNums",
LISTAGG (ga.APPL_ID, ',') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY ga.FULL_APPL_NUM) AS "ApplIds",
LISTAGG (ga.PROJECT_TITLE, ',') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY ga.FULL_APPL_NUM) AS "ProjectTitles",
```

The results look like this:

**FullApplNums**
2r01HL02858573-23A1,5R01HL02857324,...
**ApplIds**
7219924,6718409,... 
**ProjectTitles**
ProjectTitle1, ProjectTitle2,...

These columns all reference the same record from one table in a join to about 4 tables but they are all coming from the same table - ga.

I need another list agg to fill in one more column but it comes from another table aliased as pp.
Is it possible to LISTAGG again referencing another table and how would I sync up the values since the comma delimated lists are used like index arrays.
So I can build a record from ga["FULL_APPL_NUM"][0], ga["APPL_ID"][1], ga["PROJECT_TITLE"][0].

Now I need ga["IsContact"][0] but it would come from pp table not ga.

Or is it possible to do a sub select query like:
SELECT * FROM pp where appl_id in (ApplIds) -- where ApplIds is the result of a list agg.

Here is the whole query so far:

```
 PROCEDURE GetPrincipalInvestigators
      (
 loginId          IN VARCHAR2 := NULL,
 portfolioId      IN NUMBER := NULL,
 portfolioType    IN VARCHAR := NULL,
 ic               IN VARCHAR2 := NULL,
 startRow         IN INT := NULL,
 endRow           IN INT := NULL,
 sortField        IN VARCHAR2 := NULL,
 sortDirection    IN VARCHAR2 := NULL,
 PrincipalInvestigators_CUR IN OUT SYS_REFCURSOR
  )
      IS
          v_APPL_ID               NUMBER(10,0) := 0;  
  v_ADMIN_PHS_ORG_CODE    VARCHAR2(2 BYTE) := '  ';
  v_SERIAL_NUM            NUMBER(6,0) := 0;
  v_Proj_Appl_Rec         Proj_Appl_Rec;        
  v_Proj_Appl_Tab         Proj_Appl_Tab := Proj_Appl_Tab(); 
  v_Proj_Appl_Cur         SYS_REFCURSOR;
  v_sortField             VARCHAR2(50 BYTE) := NULL;
  v_sortDirection         VARCHAR2(4 BYTE)  := NULL;
  v_cnt                   NUMBER := 0;
  v_orderBy               VARCHAR2(200 BYTE) := ' ORDER BY ';
  v_sql                   CLOB := ' ';  

  BEGIN  
      IF sortField IS NULL THEN
        v_sortField := 'LAST_NAME';
      ELSE
        v_sortField := sortField;
      END IF;

      IF sortDirection IS NULL THEN
        v_sortDirection := 'DESC';
      ELSE
        v_sortDirection := sortDirection;
      END IF;

      v_orderBy := v_orderBy || v_sortField || ' ' || v_sortDirection; 
      --DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(v_orderBy); 

      IREPORT_PORTFOLIOS.GetPortfolioAppsAndProjects
      (
        loginId => loginId,
        portfolioId => portfolioId,
        portfolioType => portfolioType,
        ic => ic,
        AppIds_CUR => v_Proj_Appl_Cur
      );

      LOOP
          FETCH v_Proj_Appl_Cur         
          INTO v_APPL_ID, v_ADMIN_PHS_ORG_CODE, v_SERIAL_NUM;        
          EXIT WHEN v_Proj_Appl_Cur%NOTFOUND;        
          v_Proj_Appl_Tab.extend;
          v_cnt := v_cnt + 1;
          v_Proj_Appl_Tab(v_cnt) := Proj_Appl_Rec(v_APPL_ID, v_ADMIN_PHS_ORG_CODE, v_SERIAL_NUM);        
      END LOOP;
      CLOSE v_Proj_Appl_Cur; 

      OPEN PrincipalInvestigators_CUR FOR
          WITH projects_CTE
          AS 
          (
             SELECT DISTINCT
                    pa.APPL_ID,
                    pa.ADMIN_PHS_ORG_CODE,
                    pa.SERIAL_NUM
               FROM TABLE(v_proj_appl_tab) pa
          )

          SELECT
                pp.PERSON_PROFILE_ID AS PersonProfileId,
                pp.LAST_NAME, FIRST_NAME,
                (pp.LAST_NAME || ' , ' || pp.FIRST_NAME) AS InvestigatorName,
                pp.ORG_NAME AS PrimaryEmployer,
                pp.EMAIL_ADDR AS Email,
                pp.PHONE_NUM AS Phone,
                COUNT(*),
                LISTAGG (ga.FULL_APPL_NUM, ',') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY ga.FULL_APPL_NUM) AS "FullApplNums",
                LISTAGG (ga.APPL_ID, ',') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY ga.FULL_APPL_NUM) AS "ApplIds",
                LISTAGG (ga.PROJECT_TITLE, ',') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY ga.FULL_APPL_NUM) AS "ProjectTitles"
          FROM projects_CTE pcte
          JOIN APPL_PIS apis
          ON pcte.APPL_ID = apis.APPL_ID
          JOIN PERSON_PROFILES pp
          ON pp.PERSON_PROFILE_ID = apis.CONTACT_PI_PROFILE_PERSON_ID
          JOIN GRANT_APPLS ga
          ON ga.APPL_ID = pcte.APPL_ID
          WHERE 
          ga.APPL_TYPE_CODE <> 3  -- Non Supplement
          AND rownum < 100
          GROUP BY PERSON_PROFILE_ID, LAST_NAME, FIRST_NAME, ORG_NAME, EMAIL_ADDR,PHONE_NUM  ;

  END GetPrincipalInvestigators;
```

Sorry this is difficult to explain.
Maybe someone will have a better approach than this.

Comment: Does your query link a single `pp` record to each `ga`? If so is there a reason you think you can't have another `listagg`?

Comment: This procedure does not compile as is, does it? This implicit cursor you are wanting to modify is malformed (e.g. it is not selecting into anything).

Comment: @PatrickBacon - it's an IN OUT ref cursor, so that's fine.

Comment: @AlexPoole Yes, I did not catch that.  I am not used to seeing the CTE as part of a cursor.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you always have exactly one `pp` match per `ga` result - that is, one per group - and it isn't null, you can aggregate a column from one table while ordering by another:

```
LISTAGG (pp.IS_CONTACT, ',')
  WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY ga.FULL_APPL_NUM) AS "IsContact"
```

Ordering by the same `ga` column as the other aggregations means they entries will be in the appropriate order - so they'd be in sync. But if an `is_contact` (or whatever it is really called) is null then that won't be included, which would throw out your indexing.

Comment: It's easy enough to get around the null value issue by wrapping the column reference in the `LISTAGG` function with an `NVL` fuction: `LISTAGG (NVL(pp.IS_CONTACT,'(NULL)'), ',')
  WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY ga.FULL_APPL_NUM) AS "IsContact"`.  Generaly speaking this isn't an issue multi table aggregates, but any aggregate, since nulls are typically ignored.

Comment: Sure, but it usually doesn't matter if nulls are left out. I didn't want to overcomplicate it without knowing if there were nulls to worry about - from the name it could be not-null and constrained to Y/N, say. Who knows *8-)